# Django .. signup different type of users and handling their relevant views

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-authentication

I'm thinking on this for a while. I have at least two Actors/Roles. "Student" and "Tutors".
What I've done until now, was to make a choice field like this:

```
    class UserProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):

        Roles = [('Student' , 'Student') , ('Tutor' , 'Tutor')]
        ..
        role = models.CharField(max_length = 20 , choices = actor_type , blank = True , null = True)
```

Now I got stuck to how to divide them in the views !!

There is a way to use `user_passes_test` on top a view, but I don't know how to make groups as well ?!

If I only had a student, I could do something like this:

```
class Student(UserProfile):
    """ 
    The Student actor and its necessary fields
    """

    courses        = models.ManyToManyField('courses.Course' , null = True, blank = True, related_name = _('student') , through = 'Registration')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Student")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Students")

    def save(self , *args , **kwargs):
        super(Student , self).save(*args , **kwargs)

        user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=self.username)
        group , created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name = "Student")
        if created: group.save()
        user.groups.add(group)
        user.save()
```

Would you please show me a detailed answer on how to do this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.groups.filter(name='Student').exists())
def my_student_only_view(request):
    ...
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to work with an actual `Student` class that automatically filters to just users in the "Student" group and automatically saves users to that group, use a proxy model, and subclass `User`, not `UserProfile`:

```
class StudentManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(StudentManager, self).get_query_set(*args, **kwargs)
        return qs.filter(groups__name='Student')

class Student(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    objects = StudentManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Student')
        self.groups.add(group)
```

Comment: Thanks .. But what If I want to define Roles in the base class(as I did in the example) and make just a "unique" profile for all of my roles? I mean instead of having 2 models for "Students" and "Tutors", I only design a single model (UserProfile)? If this is also feasible, what's the procedure for making groups then? Or... maybe separating them in different models is a better way ?

Comment: I guess having different class for each role is a better way.

Comment: There's not necessarily a "better" way here. You can just use `User` straight and filter by group as needed. There's nothing wrong with that. If you want a custom class, though, you need to use a proxy model for `User`. You can then add as many or as varied methods as you want; you just change or add any additional fields.